# How to ensure groups of html elements are aligned horizontally and vertically using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

I need to provide the user certain options to choose. I have a `checkbox`, a `checkbox text`, a `dropdown` and another `checkbox`. There will be a bunch of them and I need to put them down in such a way that they are put horizontally until it takes up the full screen and then the next group is aligned vertically by the first checkbox of previous group. Here is the jsfiddle I have shared https://jsfiddle.net/tmpceqy3/

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iCheck/1.0.2/skins/all.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iCheck/1.0.2/icheck.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox">India
  <select name="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>

<div class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox">America
  <select name="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>

<div class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox">Australia
  <select name="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>

<div class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox">England
  <select name="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>

<div class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox">Holland
  <select name="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>

<div class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox">Greece
  <select name="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>

<div class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox">Egypt
  <select name="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>

<div class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox">France
  <select name="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>

<div class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox">Japan
  <select name="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>
```

Here is how it currently looks like

[image]

As you can see, I have a group of html elements per row `(checkbox, checkbox text, dropdown, checkbox)`. I have used `&nbsp` to create space between `dropdown` and `checkbox` since they both were appearing on top of another.

Now I want to put them horizontally until it takes the full screen. Then the next group should appear in the next line but vertically aligned by the first checkbox of each group in previous row.

I have tried something like `display: flex` and got something like below

[image]

It's able to split it into multiple lines but the checkboxes are screwed up.

How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: I added the code from the fiddle as a snippet, but neither show your example pictures.  Please edit the snippet to show that more accurately

Comment: Note that your fiddle has `&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp` which is not valid.

Comment: Please clearly define your desire by clarification of "checkboxes are screwed up"

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss what I mean is the first checkbox of each group in the subsequent lines must be vertically aligned with the first checkbox of the previous group of the previous row.

Comment: For example the first checkbox of India, Holland and Japan must be vertically aligned. As well for America and Greece, Australia and Egypt, England and France.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fancier style for the input elements does not come through but that is not the question here.  I put the labels in a label so I could style them a bit.

Your results may vary with the above noted difference.

```css
.my-checkbox-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.checkbox-inline {
  height: 2em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 12em;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.checkbox-inline>select {
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.checkbox-inline label {
  width: 3em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iCheck/1.0.2/skins/all.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iCheck/1.0.2/icheck.min.js"></script>
<div class="container my-checkbox-container">
  <div class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox"><label>India</label>
    <select name="cars">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <input type="checkbox">
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox"><label>America</label>
    <select name="cars">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <input type="checkbox">
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox">Australia
    <select name="cars">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <input type="checkbox">
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox"><label>England</label>
    <select name="cars">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <input type="checkbox">
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox"><label>Holland</label>
    <select name="cars">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <input type="checkbox">
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox"><label>Greece</label>
    <select name="cars">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <input type="checkbox">
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox"><label>Egypt</label>
    <select name="cars">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <input type="checkbox">
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox"><label>France</label>
    <select name="cars">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <input type="checkbox">
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox"><label>Japan</label>
    <select name="cars">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <input type="checkbox">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow this is cool! It does solves my issue. But for some reason the last check box of each group superimpose on the first checkbox of the same group. So I only see one checkbox. This only happens when display is set to `flex`. When I change to block or something else, the last check box reappears. But the drop-down alignment gets disturbed. Any idea why the last checkbox behaves like that?

Comment: Honestly I did not delve into any other CSS or constructs that might disturb the layout

Comment: Sorry mate! My bad! I was using a different version of bootstrap and so the layout came different. Using your version gives me the exact result. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Please add the class in parent like this and CSS, I have done changes in jsfield as well you could check there as well here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/cgaL462s/ :

```
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="checkbox-inline">
          <input  type="checkbox">India
          <select name="cars"><option value="volvo">Volvo</option><option value="saab">Saab</option><option value="fiat">Fiat</option><option value="audi">Audi</option> </select>
          <input  type="checkbox">
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox-inline">
          <input  type="checkbox">America
          <select name="cars"><option value="volvo">Volvo</option><option value="saab">Saab</option><option value="fiat">Fiat</option><option value="audi">Audi</option> </select>
          <input  type="checkbox">
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox-inline">
          <input  type="checkbox">Australia
          <select name="cars"><option value="volvo">Volvo</option><option value="saab">Saab</option><option value="fiat">Fiat</option><option value="audi">Audi</option> </select>
          <input  type="checkbox">
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox-inline">
          <input  type="checkbox">England
          <select name="cars"><option value="volvo">Volvo</option><option value="saab">Saab</option><option value="fiat">Fiat</option><option value="audi">Audi</option> </select>
          <input  type="checkbox">
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox-inline">
          <input  type="checkbox">Holland
          <select name="cars"><option value="volvo">Volvo</option><option value="saab">Saab</option><option value="fiat">Fiat</option><option value="audi">Audi</option> </select>
          <input  type="checkbox">
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox-inline">
          <input  type="checkbox">Greece
          <select name="cars"><option value="volvo">Volvo</option><option value="saab">Saab</option><option value="fiat">Fiat</option><option value="audi">Audi</option> </select>
          <input  type="checkbox">
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox-inline">
          <input  type="checkbox">Egypt
          <select name="cars"><option value="volvo">Volvo</option><option value="saab">Saab</option><option value="fiat">Fiat</option><option value="audi">Audi</option> </select>
          <input  type="checkbox">
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox-inline">
          <input  type="checkbox">France
          <select name="cars"><option value="volvo">Volvo</option><option value="saab">Saab</option><option value="fiat">Fiat</option><option value="audi">Audi</option> </select>
          <input  type="checkbox">
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox-inline">
          <input  type="checkbox">Japan
          <select name="cars"><option value="volvo">Volvo</option><option value="saab">Saab</option><option value="fiat">Fiat</option><option value="audi">Audi</option> </select>
          <input  type="checkbox">
        </div>
        </div>

.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.checkbox-inline {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: hey this is great! But if you observe the first checkbox of `Holland` and `France` are not aligned. Also for `Greece` and `Japan`. It should be like the way checkboxes of `India`, `England` and `Egypt` are aligned.

Comment: Then please update the CSS only I did some changes in CSS code 

`` 
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.checkbox-inline {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 33%;
}

select {
  margin: 0 5px;
}

Answer (score 0):

Made some changes in fiddle and got the desired results. Below there is link to the fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/9qfh0yum/

```
  .parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.checkbox-inline {
  width : 170px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


<div class="parent">
    <div class="checkbox-inline">
      <input  type="checkbox">India
      <select name="cars"><option value="volvo">Volvo</option><option value="saab">Saab</option><option value="fiat">Fiat</option><option value="audi">Audi</option> </select>
      <input  type="checkbox">
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox-inline">
      <input  type="checkbox">America
      <select name="cars"><option value="volvo">Volvo</option><option value="saab">Saab</option><option value="fiat">Fiat</option><option value="audi">Audi</option> </select>
      <input  type="checkbox">
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox-inline">
      <input  type="checkbox">Australia
      <select name="cars"><option value="volvo">Volvo</option><option value="saab">Saab</option><option value="fiat">Fiat</option><option value="audi">Audi</option> </select>
      <input  type="checkbox">
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox-inline">
      <input  type="checkbox">England
      <select name="cars"><option value="volvo">Volvo</option><option value="saab">Saab</option><option value="fiat">Fiat</option><option value="audi">Audi</option> </select>
      <input  type="checkbox">
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox-inline">
      <input  type="checkbox">Holland
      <select name="cars"><option value="volvo">Volvo</option><option value="saab">Saab</option><option value="fiat">Fiat</option><option value="audi">Audi</option> </select>
      <input  type="checkbox">
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox-inline">
      <input  type="checkbox">Greece
      <select name="cars"><option value="volvo">Volvo</option><option value="saab">Saab</option><option value="fiat">Fiat</option><option value="audi">Audi</option> </select>
      <input  type="checkbox">
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox-inline">
      <input  type="checkbox">Egypt
      <select name="cars"><option value="volvo">Volvo</option><option value="saab">Saab</option><option value="fiat">Fiat</option><option value="audi">Audi</option> </select>
      <input  type="checkbox">
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox-inline">
      <input  type="checkbox">France
      <select name="cars"><option value="volvo">Volvo</option><option value="saab">Saab</option><option value="fiat">Fiat</option><option value="audi">Audi</option> </select>
      <input  type="checkbox">
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox-inline">
      <input  type="checkbox">Japan
      <select name="cars"><option value="volvo">Volvo</option><option value="saab">Saab</option><option value="fiat">Fiat</option><option value="audi">Audi</option> </select>
      <input  type="checkbox">
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

when using `flex` you need to add a flex value to the children. This allows them to know what space they should take up.

Example below:

*P.S. Make sur you use `name` `id` and `for` attributes on your inputs so the browser knows what you you want to do.*

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kvL8f5h0/1/

Change the width of the window to see how it will switch between the two stlyes.

**HTML**

```html
<h1>As a list</h1>
<div>
  <div class="checkbox-inline">
    <div>
      <label for="india">
        <input id="india" name="india" type="checkbox" />
        India
      </label>
    </div>
    <select name="cars">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select make</option>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox-inline">
    <div>
      <label for="America">
        <input id="America" name="America" type="checkbox" />
        America
      </label>
    </div>
    <select name="cars">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select make</option>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox-inline">
    <div>
      <label for="Australia">
        <input id="Australia" name="Australia" type="checkbox" />
        Australia
      </label>
    </div>
    <select name="cars">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select make</option>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox-inline">
    <div>
      <label for="England">
        <input id="England" name="England" type="checkbox" />
        England
      </label>
    </div>
    <select name="cars">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select make</option>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox-inline">
    <div>
      <label for="Holland">
        <input id="Holland" name="Holland" type="checkbox" />
        Holland
      </label>
    </div>
    <select name="cars">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select make</option>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<hr />
<h1>Now in a row / responsive</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="checkbox-inline">
    <div>
      <label for="india">
        <input id="india" name="india" type="checkbox" />
        India
      </label>
    </div>
    <select name="cars">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select make</option>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox-inline">
    <div>
      <label for="America">
        <input id="America" name="America" type="checkbox" />
        America
      </label>
    </div>
    <select name="cars">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select make</option>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox-inline">
    <div>
      <label for="Australia">
        <input id="Australia" name="Australia" type="checkbox" />
        Australia
      </label>
    </div>
    <select name="cars">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select make</option>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox-inline">
    <div>
      <label for="England">
        <input id="England" name="England" type="checkbox" />
        England
      </label>
    </div>
    <select name="cars">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select make</option>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox-inline">
    <div>
      <label for="Holland">
        <input id="Holland" name="Holland" type="checkbox" />
        Holland
      </label>
    </div>
    <select name="cars">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select make</option>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.checkbox-inline {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: left;
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.checkbox-inline>* {
  flex: 1;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.checkbox-inline>select {
  flex: 2;
}


.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: left;
}
```

Comment: Hey the checkboxes must be put horizontally until it fills the screen and then the vertical alignment should happen.

Comment: If the amount of inputs are always the same, you could look at css media queries for device width.